# Radius calculation for cluster

Tags: clustering

I am working on a clustering algorithm using cosine distance for measuring similarity between points. Can anyone help with a formula to find the radius of the cluster based on aggregate statistics of the points in the cluster, since the actual points in the cluster are not available.

Points in the cluster are vectors with 50 dimensions.

`radius` is defined as half of the maximum distance between any pair of points.

`aggregate statistics` currently being stored are linear sum and square sum of the points(vectors), but any other aggregate statistic can be used.

Comment: Could you tell us how you define the "radius"?  What "aggregate statistics" are available?

Comment: "radius" is something like half of the maximum distance between any pair of points. The current "aggregate statistics" that I am storing currently are linear sum and square sum but any other aggregate statistic can be recorded as needed

Comment: The answer will depend partly on which distance you use.  Regardless, you won't be able to recover the radius from just those two statistics.  In principle, the only "aggregate statistic" that will work would be equivalent to that radius or would be so detailed (such as a list of the individual points) that the radius can be computed from it.  This is the case even in one dimension.

Comment: agreed. as mentioned we would be using the cosine distance. For other cases, like with manhattan distance sqrt{SS/N - (LS/N)^2} gives us the radius according to one of the papers where SS is the square sum, LS is the linear sum and N is the number of points in the cluster.

Just wanted to know if we can do something similar for cosine distances as well

Comment: my bad the formula in the above comment was for euclidean distance, not manhattan